# Get DIV Name by its ID with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, html

Lets say I have on page that runs GWT widget:

```
 <div name="foo" id="123"></div>
```

How do I retrieve the name `"foo"` if I want to search for it with the div's ID `"123"` using the widget that is running on that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DOM.getElementById("123").getAttribute("name")**, I think.